# How can I make a link to the same page on a different site?

Tags: php, html, url-routing

So I have a test version of my site. In the header of the test server, I'd like to include a link to same page on the live server.
Is there an HTML or PHP means of "knowing" what the current page is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PHP you can use:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

A hyperlink would look like this:

```
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">Click for current page</a>
```

Note that `PHP_SELF` will show only the filename, and not the `GET` params.

If the url is like: `index.php?page=aboutus`

`REQUEST_URI` would be `index.php?page=aboutus`

while `PHP_SELF` would be `index.php`

Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Or `$_SEVER['REQUEST_URL'];` if the OP requires the entire path.

Comment: fix the two spelling errors (SERVER, _URI) and I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: And an explanation of the difference bewteen REQUEST_URI and PHP_SELF to. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">Click me!</a>
```

or alternatively,

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two?

Comment: PHP_SELF is only the address of the current script. REQUEST_URI is the URI the user used to access the page, which may include a query string (aka $_GET variables).

Answer (score 1):

There is JavaScript's [window.location](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location) - Object, which makes many useful information available. There is also

> $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

on the PHP side, as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your test server is `http://test.site.com`, and your live server is `http://site.com`, then you could just use an absolute URL:

```
<a href="http://site.com/thepage.html">thepage.html on live server</a>
```

In PHP, [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables will get URL parts.  In JavaScript, document.URL is the place to start.  :)